# Parent view -> Subview -> button -> subview method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a parentview with a ui view on it. This loads a subviewcontroller on viewdidload. The subviewcontroller has a button on it that is linked up on touch up inside to a subviewcontroller method called clicked.

This causes a bad access error to fire and crashes the app. My question is, is this setup possible or do I have to have the method in the parent view? The subview will be loaded in 8 different parentviews so I would like to keep the method in the subview.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to post the relevant code around the crash.

Comment: It crashes when the method runs. The method is empty, I would like to know what is the best practise for this rather than being code specific. Thanks

Comment: Any setup is possible. Crashes are code specific.

Comment: I know I've spent almost two years, but I have this same problem.  It is driving me crazy.. Did You find any solution? Thanks

Comment: yeah the key is to use a delegate so the subview.delegate = parentview, see @VdesmedT answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good approach for this kind of setup is to have a protocol including the click message, a delegate property of type id in the view containing the button and a method in the same view that fires the delegated message like so [self.delegate clicked].  The TouchUpInside event is linked to that method in IB and the parent view set itself as delegate of the subview and conform itself to the protocol.  It can sounds a bit tricky but its definitely the proper way to do.

the Protocol

```
@protocol viewWithButtonDelegate
  -(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button inView:(UIView*)view;
@end
```

in the subview interface

```
@interface viewWithButton {
...
id<viewWithButtonDelegate> delegate;
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<viewWithButtonDelegate> delegate
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
...
@end
```

in the subview implementation

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
  if([sender class] == [UIButton class]) {
    [self.delegate buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender inView:self]
  }
}
```

the controller interface is declared like this

```
@interface myController<viewWithButtonDelegate>
```

and finally in the controller implementation :

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button inView:(UIView*)view {
  //do something in response to button clicked
}
```

hope this helps...